# Array.reduce gives wrong result type

Tags: typescript, types

I found a very surprising behavior of Typescript's type-inference and suspect if it is a bug.

Suppose I have a list of `MyItem` interface.

```
interface MyItem {
    id?: string;
    value: string;
}
const myItemList: MyItem[] = [];
```

Please notice that the `MyItem.id` is optional while `MyItem.value` is mandatory.

I want to use method `Array.reduce` on `myList`, like this

```
const myMap = myItemList.reduce((accum, item) => ({ ...accum, [item.id!]: item }), {});
```

This will make the result variable `myMap` to be of type `{}`, which is as expected because I supplies `{}` as the initial value in `myItemList.reduce(...)`, as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Now, the problem occurs when I modify the `MyItem` interface so that the `value` becomes optional.

```
interface MyItem {
    id?: string;
    value?: string; // << here I make it optional
}
const myItemList: MyItem[] = [];
```

Surprisingly, the exact same `myItemList.reduce(...)` statement yields a result of `MyItem` instead of `{}`.

Is this a bug? If not, please help me understand what is the reason behind it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a TS expert, but this doesn't seem *too* surprising to me: if both fields of the interface are optional, then any empty object is potentially a valid `MyItem` instance. So when the system sees an empty object and tries tries to infer a type for it, `MyItem` is a match.

I'm assuming that TS defines an "optional" field as including "undefined/absent" and not "existent, but potentially holding `undefined` or `null`", which would be closer to a `Nullable<T>` field in, for example, C#/.NET. Considering it's non-trivial the tell the two cases apart in JS<sup>*</sup>, this seems like the more reasonable definition if you're coming from a JS background.

---

<sup>*</sup> You'd have to use `prop in obj`; `obj.prop === undefined` for *both* `obj = {}` and `obj = {prop: undefined}`, even in strict mode(!)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a hint in @solarshado's answer, I have investigated further and found that this is not the wrong type-inference. It is the expected behavior of method overloading resolution.

Javascript's Array has 2 overloading methods with signature matched the parameters in the statement `myItemList.reduce((accum, item) => ({ ...accum, [item.id!]: item }), {});`

Which are

```
1. reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => T, initialValue: T): T;
2. reduce<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => U, initialValue: U): U;
```

It surprised me because the expectation in my mind is that I am using the second overload (`reduce<U>(...)`). But actually, the compiler used the first overload for some reason (maybe related to the overload resolution algorithm).

Therefore my problem should be solved by providing more information to the compiler to pick up the correct overload.

E.g.

```
const myMap = myItemList.reduce<{}>((accum, item) => ({ ...accum, [item.id!]: item }), {});
```

Or the more specific one

```
const myMap = myItemList.reduce<{[id: string]: MyItem}>((accum, item) => ({ ...accum, [item.id!]: item }), {});
```